# Sign-up verification email being sent in Markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, email, sign-up

I just signed up for an account and I received an email in unparsed Markdown, which my client does not understand:

```
You're almost done!

[Click here to complete your registration](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/signup-finish?email=[REDACTED]&name=J.B.+Lee&token=[REDACTED]&sus=hero&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fmath.stackexchange.com%2f&authCode[REDACTED])

_________________________________________________________________________

Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com). 

Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038
```

Comment: Well tell your just enter the entire link in the parentheses (the first one) to finish

Comment: I know what to do. It's just not very user-friendly

Comment: We do send both HTML and Markdown in the email - if your email client does not see the HTML, it will see the markdown - we do this in order to make it clear what the links are and what the text that accompanies them is.

Comment: @rene Nah, these emails don't go anywhere near Zendesk.

Comment: What client? Does your email client support HTML emails? Do you get other emails as HTML? Your bug report is lacking crucial details...

Comment: @AdamLear please provide an [mcve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) ...nvm,  I take your word for it ...